# sets theory-Realation proof question

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-explanation, relations

Let $A,B,C$ and $R,S,T$ be sets. 
And assume that

$$ R \subseteq A \times B, ~~ S \subseteq B \times C, ~~
T \subseteq B \times C.$$

Then, I want to show that 
$$
\begin{equation}
(S \circ R) \cap (T \circ R) \subseteq (S\cap T) \circ R, \\
(S \circ R) \cup (T \circ R) = (S \cup T) \circ R.
\end{equation}
$$

I tried solving this for hours.
I have no idea to even handle this.
I would love any kind of help or assistence.
Thank you.

Comment: What do you know about set theory already? What text is this problem from? What course are you taking? Providing information like this would be a suitable alternative to any ideas you have to solve the problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If a(R o (S $\cap$ T))c, then exists
b in B with aRb and b(S $\cap$ T)c.
Thus aRb, bSc and bTc;  a(RoS)c, a(RoT)c.
In conclusion, R o (S $\cap$ T) subset RoS $\cap$ RoT.

a(R o (S $\cup$ T))c iff exists b in B with
aRb, b(S $\cup$ T)c iff aRb and (bSc or bTc)
iff (aRb and bSc) or (aRb and bTc)
iff a(RoS)c or a(RoT)c.
In conclusion R o (S $\cup$ T) = RoS $\cup$ RoT.

Note that I'm using the conventions aRb for (a,b) in R and
for composition RoS ={ (a,c) : exists b with (aRb and bSc) }

Comment: Many thanks! Helped me alot

Comment: @William: You've been on the site long enough to have a general idea how to use MathJax, and not rely on the kindness of others to make your posts look good. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773). Please look into it.